# Fixed-Point Types - "exact value or not"?

Tags: php, mysql, decimal, numeric

i need to create a column, where values from "0.0 - 99.99" can be stored.

Why? because of this scenario:

I have this table in my database:

```
"CREATE TABLE dumps(
                id INT NOT NULL auto_increment,
                dump_value NUMERIC(5,2),
                PRIMARY KEY(id),
                UNIQUE KEY dump_value (dump_value))";
```

When i insert the value "1.0", i get this in my table: "1.00", that´s because NUMERIC expects it to be exactly two digit´s long yea?
But when i change my table to this:

```
"CREATE TABLE dumps(
                id INT NOT NULL auto_increment,
                dump_value NUMERIC(5,1), // <---- CHANGED
                PRIMARY KEY(id),
                UNIQUE KEY dump_value (dump_value))";
```

i have problem´s with inserting value´s like "50.44", because in my table is just "50.4" saved, wo what do i have to change?
greetings

Comment: What is wrong with `1.00`? If you are worried for display purposes then let your display code handle formatting numbers, not the database.

Comment: storage and display should be handled differently,they have different purpose

Comment: i need to store exactly the value given, because of later operations, so how to do this?

Comment: @user2999787 What do you need to do with this data that you can't with the current format? `1 + 2 = 3` `1.00 + 2 = 3` `1.00000000000000000000000000000000000 + 2 = 3` It all calculates the same **unless** we are talking about displaying it on a screen to a user. If we are talking about displaying it to a user then fixing this at the database level is **wrong**.

Answer (score 0):

why is it a Problem that it changes "1.0" to "1.00". this would not Change something in the calculations and you can still store the values "00.00" to "99.99".

Comment: because i need to do some more things with those data later, so could you tell me how to solve my problem? greetings! :)

Comment: in my opinion i would Change the datatype to float and let the program check that the inserted values have only the Digits after the dot. for example in php the code that cuts every Digits after the 2 desired is:
`$desired = ((int)($value * 100) / 100) % 100`
if $value is the value you want to insert into the database, $desired is a float with only 2 or less Digits ofter the dot (because of the part in the parentheses) and in the range of 0 to 99.99 (thanks to the "%100" part). i hope i could help you with my answer and please apologize my bad english

Comment: sorry but i didnt unterstand what you exactly mean :/ anybody could help? greetings!

Comment: the Format NUMERIC(5, 2) is the Format you want, except it keeps changing something like 2.0 to 2.00. the FLOAT datatype is nearly the same, but it supports much more decimal places, so your program has to Change the values you insert, so numbers like 1000.9 or 30.928 do not appear in the database. if you are working with php, this line of code i wrote you checks $value and cuts unnessary decimal places and keeps $value in the desired range of 0 to 99.
all in all you can say: Change the datatype to FLOAT and it will not Change 2.0 to 2.00, but you could insert 2.001 in the database

Answer (score 0):

According to [MySQL documentation for NUMERIC](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fixed-point-types.html) your definition should be

```
dump_value NUMERIC(4,2) UNSIGNED
```

This will define column for total four digits with two after decimal point.

In your changed example you define dump_value to contain just one digit after decimal point.